# Ignore changes in schema while loading from gcs (json format) to BigQury using java

Tags: java, api, google-bigquery

I have one java based micro service to load data from gcs ( json formatted) to Bigquery.It is running fine if I am getting same schema structure in event as defined in bigquery but it is failing in case of change in event.
I have a requirement where I should be able to ignore the schema changes in json ( any new attributes addition will be ignored) at runtime while loading from gcs to BigQuery.

Is there approach to do the same?

```
createJob(String formatOptions, JSONObject additionalFormatOptions, String createDisposition,
                           String writeDisposition, String projectId, String datasetId, String tableId,
                           List<String> cloudStorageUris, boolean autodetect, Integer maxBadRecords)
```